# How to get the device time format in XamarinForms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

For UWP desktop we can get desktop time format using shorttimepattern https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shorttimepattern(v=vs.110).aspx,
like how can we get the device time format in (xamariniOS,android,windows)

Please share yor valuable suggestion.

Comment: which format do you want? hh:mm:ss or hh:mm?

Comment: same format works for xamarin

Comment: Did you solv it?

Comment: it device time format settings (12 or 24 hours format) . got solution DateFormat.Is24HourFormat(this) . its works

Answer (score -1):

An answer for Xamarin.iOS

```
using System;  

namespace DateTimeFormat
{  
     class Program  
     {  
         static void Main(string[] args)  
         {   
             DateTime aDate = DateTime.Now; 
             Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));  
             Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy"));  
             Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy"));  
             Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy"));  
             Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy"));  
             Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy"));  
             Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"));  
             Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"));  
             Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt"));  
             Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy H:mm"));  
             Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt"));  
             Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));  
             Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("MMMM dd"));  
             Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("yyyy’-‘MM’-‘dd’T’HH’:’mm’:’ss.fffffffK"));  
             Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyy HH’:’mm’:’ss ‘GMT’"));  
             Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("yyyy’-‘MM’-‘dd’T’HH’:’mm’:’ss"));  
             Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("HH:mm"));  
             Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("hh:mm tt"));  
             Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("H:mm"));  
             Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("h:mm tt"));  
             Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));  
             Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("yyyy MMMM"));  
             Console.ReadKey();  
        }  
    }  
}
```

I had write all the time and formats in this console code.